# Location tracking while app running in the background

Tags: ios, core-location

I have an app which can track the current location of the device when running in the foreground. I want to do the same when running in the background also.

I have done some research and tried the following:

- applied `setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{ [self backgroundHandler]; }];`

When the app is being run under debugging everything works fine (I mean when device is connected to mac pc or device connected for charging). When the device is disconnected from PC or charging app can't track the current location while app running in background.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the UIBackgroundModes key to your info.plist file. This key should be an array, and then you need to add the value "location" to it.

More info:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

Comment: I have added everything. in info.plist i have added strings like voip, location and audio also.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Breadcrumbs sample app and the WWDC 2010 lecture on using CoreLocation while backgrounded.  The lecture goes through the Breadcrumbs sample.